# Как подключить к Робокассе приложение Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Установил гем [rubykassa](https://github.com/ZeroOneStudio/rubykassa) не могу разобраться, поскольку делаю впервые.
Предполагается, что пользователь заполняет форму с нужными параметрами и... как сделать, чтобы при сабмите получить шифрование MD5 и отправку в Робокассу?
В описании есть хелпер:

```
<%= pay_url "Pay with Robokassa", ivoice_id, total_sum %>
```

Но как его привязать к отправке формы, я не очень понимаю.